# Even though I have declared an identifier I keep getting an undeclared identifier error in visual studio 2019 using c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

This might just turn into a daily post kind of thing until I get the hang of it and I am very sorry if that is annoying to anyone but this is the only way I can learn without spending more money to lengthen my college degree.

So to the main problem. I am using an identifier called 'i' but the code says that it is undefined even though in other places it is defined and working fine. The code that I will post below consists of Game.cpp (The top code) and Game.h (the bottom code).

```
#include "Game.h"


Game::Game()
{
    choice = 0;
    playing = true;
    activeCharacter = 0;
    fileName = "characters.txt";
}

Game::~Game()
{

}

 //Functions

void Game::initGame()
{
    createNewCharacter();
}

void Game::mainMenu()
{
    std::cout << "= MAIN MENU =" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "0: Quit" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "1: Travel" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "2: Shop" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "3: Level Up" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "4: Rest" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "5: Character Sheet" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "6: Create new Character" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "7: Save characters" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "8: Load characters" << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::endl << "Choice: ";
    std::cin >> choice;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    switch (choice)
    {
    case 0:

        playing = false;

        break;

    case 5:
        characters[activeCharacter].printStats();
        break;

    case 6:
        std::cin.ignore();
        createNewCharacter();
        saveCharacters();
        break;

    case 7:
        saveCharacters();
        break;

    case 8:
        loadCharacters();
        break;

    default:
        break;

    }
}

void Game::createNewCharacter()
{

    std::string name;
    std::cout << "Character name: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, name);

    characters.push_back(Character());
    activeCharacter = characters.size() - 1;
    characters[activeCharacter].initialize(name);

}

void Game::saveCharacters()
{
    std::ofstream outFile(fileName);

    if (outFile.is_open())
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < characters.size(); i++);
        {
            outFile << characters[i].getAsString() << "\n";
        }
    } 

    outFile.close();
}   

void Game::loadCharacters()
{

}


#pragma once

#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<string>


class Item
{
private:
    std::string name;
    int buyValue;
    int sellValue;

public:
    Item();
    virtual ~Item();

    inline std::string debugPrint() const
    {
        return this->name;
    }
};
```

THe problem is occurring towards the bottom of Game.cpp. The line in question is 'outFile << characters[i].getAsString() << "\n";' I keep getting the error for the bracketted i.

Comment: You have an extra `;` at the end of the `for` loop, so `i` is not in scope in the next line.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate it. That fixed it instantly. Haha sorry about making such a simple mistake.

Comment: No problem :) You can delete the question if you want, since it's not really going to be useful to others.

Answer (score 3):

You've got an extra semicolon after your for-loop.

```cpp
 for (size_t i = 0; i < characters.size(); i++);
//                                             ^ here
```

That's why the statements in the curly braces are not counted as part of the loop any more and hence `i` is not defined.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate it

Comment: @mashackl You can accept the answer as a thank you if it did solve your problem.